autoselect second dropdown based on selection of first
Need help with jquery script to auto select one of two drop down select box based on manual selection or manual change in either one dropdown.
Form has two drop down selection box, REGNUM and FNAME , Selecting from any one dropdown should auto select another,in both dropdown value in both dropdown is ID number in database.
DB Table:

UID    REGNUM  FNAME     EMAIL
 1      007    James     jbond@
 2      005    Jane      janedoe@
 3      003    John      johndoe@ 

<select id="regnum">
    <option value="1">007</option>
    <option value="2">005</option>
    <option value="3">003</option>
</select>

<select id="fname">
    <option value="1">James</option>
    <option value="2">Jane</option>
    <option value="3">John</option>
</select>

Tried tho check how to do, print Value of selected value from regnum and pass value to fname select .
    $('#regnum').click(function () {
    $('#regnum option:selected').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).val());    
    var vregnum = $(this).val();
    $("#fname option[$vregnum]").attr('selected', true); 
});

});


Please show us what you have tried to create this script yourself

your are close. u simply made the mistake to add an $ to the var name. By removing it your logging works and this will also work for your goal to select the dropdown from both

With this u can select the dropdown from each other:


$('#regnum').change(function() {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $('#fname').val(selectedValue);
    });




You could do it like this:
$("#regnum, #fname").change(function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $("#regnum, #fname").not(this).val(v)
})

This code works for both dropdowns, and then you change 1, then the other will change to match the value.
Demo


$("#regnum, #fname").change(function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $("#regnum, #fname").not(this).val(v)
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="regnum">
    <option value="1">007</option>
    <option value="2">005</option>
    <option value="3">003</option>
</select>

<select id="fname">
    <option value="1">James</option>
    <option value="2">Jane</option>
    <option value="3">John</option>
</select>



